# Error in code to create a Google Virtual Machine that supports Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, virtual-machine

Google labs provided me the next code as a .yaml file to create a virtual machine that allow me to run Android studio and get some info from the Android studio emulator API to logstash / elasticsearch.

To be honest I´m new and not sure why I´m getting the error. I think is related to text in '' and/or {} but not sure.

Any help more than apreciate!!!

```
resources:

- type: gcp-types/compute-v1:instances

  name: dev-vm

  properties:

    zone: {{ properties["zone"] }}

    machineType: zones/{{ properties["zone"] }}/machineTypes/n1-highmem-4

    disks:

    - boot: true

      autoDelete: true

      initializeParams:

        sourceImage: projects/qwiklabs-resources/global/images/vnc-android-pie-tensorflow

    networkInterfaces:

    - network: global/networks/default

      accessConfigs:

      - name: External NAT

        type: ONE_TO_ONE_NAT

    serviceAccounts:

      - email: default

        scopes:

          - 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud.useraccounts.readonly'

          - 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only'

          - 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write'

          - 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.write'

    tags:

      items:

        - "vnc"

    metadata:

      items:

      - key: startup-script-url

        value: https://storage.googleapis.com/cloud-training/gsp296/setup.sh

- name: vnc-firewall-rule

  type: compute.v1.firewall

  properties:

    sourceRanges: [0.0.0.0/0]

    allowed:

    - IPProtocol: tcp

      ports:

      - 5901
      - 6901
```